# Why are there two home folders in my Ubuntu 18.04 installation?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, hard-disk, ssd, home

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10 on my computer (SSD 96GB + HDD 1TB). The SSD drive has two major partitions (excluding recovery and efi):

- Windows partition (containing windows 10)
- Ubuntu partition (containing  /(root) and swap)

The HDD drive also has two partitions, one containing files (documents, music etc.) for windows while on the other partition is mounted /home.

[image]

If I use the *disks* tool however, I can see that inside the root folder there is another /home/my_username folder, which contains the same subfolders and files as the "real"  /home located on the HDD drive.

How is this possible? Is it normal? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please post the result of the *disks* tool you used.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the "disks" tool that you mention, I'm also uncertain about what the two directories that you say seem to be identical are (one is `/home/username`, but the other?)

Answer (score 0):

Is normal don' t worry, the home is mounted in the HDD drive.
The home is located in `/home/mattia` but is mounted in the HDD drive, so is physically there.
Is like a link with the time this will be very clear to you.